# What is the most up-voted question and answer in this site?

Tags: discussion

Am just wondering, what is the most up-voted question and answer in this site?

Answer (score 5):

As of now, the highest-voted question is this:

[How can I keep my cat off my keyboard?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/9531/15) (112 +113/-1)

and the highest voted answer is this:

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2091/15 126: +131/-5)

---

The simplest way for any user to check this is by [searching `is:question score:100`](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A100) The minimum score can be increased as more questions join the ranks. As of now, only 1 question has achieved such a high score. We can [search for an answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A100) the same way. As of now there are only two answers achieving a score of over 100.